# dotnetcore GetTypeInfo() not defined on variables of type object?

Tags: c#, .net-core

the code below is a stripped down version of the original code that demonstrates the problem. In dotnetcore (1.0.1) .IsEnum property is moved to System.Reflection. I made changes that all work as expected.  However, the one I cannot make to work is of type object.

Compiler throws this error:
c:\tmp\netcore\repro\Program.cs(14,17): error CS0103: The name 't' does not exist in the current context

```
public class Program
{
    enum Kleur {Red, Blue, Green}

    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        object myType = Kleur.Green;
        if (myType.GetTypeInfo().IsEnum)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Yes its an enum");
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a workaround to test if an object is of type Enum in dotnetcore? Is there a specific reason why there is no extension method for type object (all other types I needed seem to work).

Answer (score 6):

When moving from `Type` to `TypeInfo`, the replacement for `.GetType()` is not just `.GetTypeInfo()`, it's `.GetType().GetTypeInfo()`. That's because `Type` was not removed, it was instead split into `Type`, which contains only some basic members, and `TypeInfo`, which has the rest.

So, your code should be:

```
object myType = Kleur.Green;
if (myType.GetType().GetTypeInfo().IsEnum)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Yes its an enum");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

myType.GetType().IsEnum works for me (since its object). Yes, in a .Net Core console app.